# laravel5.2 Mailgun work but not send the email

Tags: laravel-5, mailgun

Hello I setup mailgun correctly. and  did form contact us.
[image]

To send the message to my email by this code

```
public function send_contact_us()
    {

        $data = array(
            'name' => Request::get('name'),'email'=>Request::get('email'),'subject'=> Request::get('subject'));
        $client_m=Request::get('message');
        $data_message=array('message_c'=>$client_m);

         echo "we above MAIL";
        Mail::send('emails.message',$data_message, function ($message)use ($data) {
            $message->from($data['email'], 'E-SHOPPER');

            $message->to("azharnabil013@yahoo.com")->subject($data['subject']);

        });

        return view('contact_us', array('title' => 'Welcome', 'description' => '', 'page' => 'contact_us','subscribe'=>'','sent'=>"Message has been sent successfuly"));
    }
```

The code run correctly and this page display
[image]

But when I check my email I didn't find any message
I don't know why this problem .please, anyone help me.

Comment: Try calling count(Mail::failures()) right after your Mail::send() and see if it contains anything.

Comment: I try calling count(Mail::failures()) and return 0 what is it mean?